# Mysql custom order by and alphabetical order by:

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table[$a]` ORDER BY FIELD(typeof,'pdf','swf','img','web')";
```

to select and customly order my mysql query, it works great except there are multiple files within each typeof and I now want to order them alphabetically yet retaining their typeof order. Make sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `$table[$a]` 
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(typeof,'pdf','swf','img','web'), --first order by type
  filename  --then by filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table[$a]` ORDER BY FIELD(typeof,'pdf','swf','img','web'), name ASC";
```

Not sure if that'll work

Answer (score 2):

```
... ORDER BY FIELD(typeof,'pdf','swf','img','web'), name
```