# MySQL select with statements

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm learning some more SQL, and ran into a "problem",

I have two tabels like the link below
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/403d4/1

EDIT:
Since I'm quite retarded now from all SQL-test i have done this weekend, i asked really wrong...
Sorry guys...

What i really wanted:

If i have the requested language, i want to get all the records, and if the requested language is not in the titles-table, i want it to say "" or null...

like if i ask for all records in 'de', i want:

```
1  |  ACHTUNG
2  |  NULL
```

and if i ask for all the records in 'en' i want

```
1  |  WARNING
2  |  Ambulance
```

Really sorry for the wrong question.

/*
What i want to do:
I have the ID of a record and the requested language.
If the selected language does not exsists, i want it to take the other language.

like if i have:
language = 'de' and id = 1 
I want 'ACHTUNG',

if i have:
language = 'de' and id = 2
i want "Ambulance" since there's no 'de'...
*/

How do i do this?

Comment: sounds like a IF statement to me.

Comment: check my edited answer based on your edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/403d4/89

```
SELECT rec.id, title.name
FROM Records rec
LEFT JOIN Titles title ON title.record_id = rec.id and title.language='de';

SELECT rec.id, title.name
FROM Records rec
LEFT JOIN Titles title ON title.record_id = rec.id and title.language='en';


ID  NAME
1   ACHTUNG
2   (null)

ID  NAME
1   Warning
2   Ambulance
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a custom order by and only return the first row, like this:

```
SELECT
    rec.id,
    title.language,
    title.name

FROM Records rec

LEFT JOIN Titles title
ON title.record_id = rec.id

WHERE rec.id = 1
ORDER BY Field(title.language, "de") DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query returns the record with your desired language first, if one exists. If not, it will just return what was found. You might want to take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024854/mysql-custom-order-by-and-alphabetical-order-by).