# If not exists in another table, set to NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Since I asked wrong in another thread and it was correctly answered, I start a new thread instead..

I have two tables

```
Records
id  |  type
------------
1   |  CD
2   |  CD

Titles
record_id  |  name     |  language
-------------------------------
1          |  Warning  |  'en'
1          |  Achtung  |  'de'
2          | Ambulance |  'en'
```

(SQL Fiddle in link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/403d4/1)

If I request for the language 'en' i want:

```
1  |  Warning
2  |  Ambulance
```

and if I ask for 'de' I want

```
1  |  ACHTUNG
2  |  NULL
```

How do I write the SQL to get this result?

Comment: After you changed your question I already answered this question too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select with statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334594/mysql-select-with-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/403d4/89

```
SELECT rec.id, title.name
FROM Records rec
LEFT JOIN Titles title ON title.record_id = rec.id and title.language='de';

SELECT rec.id, title.name
FROM Records rec
LEFT JOIN Titles title ON title.record_id = rec.id and title.language='en';


ID  NAME
1   ACHTUNG
2   (null)

ID  NAME
1   Warning
2   Ambulance
```

Answer (score 0):

Left Outer Join supplies null values in the second table if no corresponding record exists.

Obviously change 'en' to 'de' to see the other result:

```
Select
  r.id,
  t.name
From
  Records r
    Left Outer Join
  Titles t
    On r.id = t.record_id
Where
  r.language = 'en'
```